# How do you programmatically set AWS S3 object meta data when uploading a file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you programmatically set AWS S3 object meta data when uploading a file in Javascript?

I'm wanting to set the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers for each file so I don't have to manually change the headers later.

When I try the below code, I get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined".

If I take out the middleware code, the file uploads successfully, but I have to manually set the metadata via S3 console.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: projectBucketName,
      Key: jobKey,
      Body: file
    }
    //tags: [{ Key: 'Content-Type', Value: 'application/pdf' }, { Key: 'Content-Disposition', Value: 'inline' }]
  });

  upload.middlewareStack.add(
  (next, context) => async (args) => {
    args.request.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf";
    const result = next(args);
    // result.response contains data returned from next middleware.
    return result;
  },
  {
    step: "build",
    name: "addContentTypeMetadataMiddleware",
    tags: ["METADATA", "CONTENTTYPE"],
  }
);

  upload.middlewareStack.add(
  (next, context) => async (args) => {
    args.request.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline";
    const result = next(args);
    // result.response contains data returned from next middleware.
    return result;
  },
  {
    step: "build",
    name: "addContentDispositionMetadataMiddleware",
    tags: ["METADATA", "CONTENTDISPOSITION"],
  }
);



   promise = await upload.promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

To set metadata on an onject, you can use the S3 API. Here is an example that is implemented in Java. You can port this to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript.

```
public static String putS3Object(S3Client s3,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String objectKey,
                                     String objectPath) {

        try {

           // Define the metadata
            Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
            metadata.put("author", "Mary Doe");
            metadata.put("version", "1.0.0.0");

            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .metadata(metadata)
                    .build();

            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

            return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Return a byte array
    private static byte[] getObjectFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
```